# How to use PyMongo find() to search nested array attribute?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

Using PyMongo, how would one find/search for the documents where the nested array json object matches a given string.

Given the following 2 Product JSON documents in a MongoDB collection..

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5be1a1b2aa21bb3ceac339b0"),
    "id" : "1",
    "prod_attr" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Branded X 1 Sneaker"
        },  
        {
            "hierarchy" : {
                "dept" : "10",
                "class" : "101",
                "subclass" : "1011"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("7be1a1b2aa21bb3ceac339xx"),
    "id" : "2",
    "prod_attr" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Branded Y 2 Sneaker"
        },  
        {
            "hierarchy" : {
                "dept" : "10",
                "class" : "101",
                "subclass" : "2022"
            }
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I would like to 
1. return all documents where  prod_att.hierarchy.subclass = "2022"
2. return all documents where prod_attr.name contains "Sneaker"

I appreciate the JSON could be structured differently, unfortunately that is not within my control to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Return all documents where prod_attr.hierarchy.subclass = "2022"

Based on the [Query an Array of Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#use-the-array-index-to-query-for-a-field-in-the-embedded-document) documentation of MongoDB you can use dot notation concatenating the name of the array field (`prod_attr`), with a dot (`.`) and the name of the field in the nested document (`hierarchy.subclass`):

```
collection.find({"prod_attr.hierarchy.subclass": "2022"})
```

#### 2. Return all documents where prod_attr.name contains "Sneaker"

As before, you can use the dot notation to query a field of a nested element inside an array.
To perform the "contains" query you have to use the [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex) operator:

```
collection.find({"prod_attr.name": {"$regex": "Sneaker"}})
```

---

Another option is to use the MongoDB **Aggregation framework**:

```
collection.aggregate([
    {"$unwind": "$prod_attr"},
    {"$match": {"prod_attr.hierarchy.subclass": "2022"}}
])
```

the `$unwind` operator creates a new object for each object inside the `prod_attr` array, so you will have only nested documents and no array (check the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) for details).
The next step is the `$match` operator that actually perform a query on the nested object.

This is a simple example but playing with the [Aggregators Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#aggregation-expression-operators) you have a lot of flexibility.